# Assigning a value in SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

I have the below query

```
  SELECT
  R.CATENTRY_ID_PARENT AS PARENT,
  R.CATENTRY_ID_CHILD AS CHILD,
D.NAME AS NAME, 
INTEGERVALUE AS INTEGERVALUE,STRINGVALUE AS STRINGVALUE,
                D.SHORTDESCRIPTION AS SDESC, D.LONGDESCRIPTION AS LDESC, D.keyword AS KEYWORD, C.MFPARTNUMBER AS HOLIMAGEPATH, avl.topimage AS THUMB,
                    (case when (exists (Select INTEGERVALUE from xstoreattrval M1 where M1.store_id =10051 and M1.xstoreattr_id in (select xstoreattr_id from xstoreattr M2 where M2.name in ('hasClubExlusives')))) then INTEGERVALUE else null end) as INTEGERVALUE,
                    (case when (exists (Select STRINGVALUE from attrvalue M3 where M3.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from attribute M4 where M4.name in ('clubExclusive') and M4.catentry_id=CAT1ID))) then STRINGVALUE else null end) as STRINGVALUE,
                    C.CATENTRY_ID as CAT1ID
                    FROM CATENTREL R, CATENTRY C, CATENTDESC D, XCATENTAVL avl,                 
                    (Select INTEGERVALUE from xstoreattrval M1 where M1.store_id =10051 and M1.xstoreattr_id in (select xstoreattr_id from xstoreattr M2 where M2.name in ('hasClubExlusives'))) as INTEGERVALUE,
                    (Select STRINGVALUE from attrvalue M3 where M3.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from attribute M4 where M4.name in ('clubExclusive') and M4.catentry_id=CAT1ID)) as STRINGVALUE
                    --INNER JOIN ATTRVALUE V ON  V.CATENTRY_ID = C.CATENTRY_ID 
                    --INNER JOIN ATTRIBUTE AT ON V.ATTRIBUTE_ID = AT.ATTRIBUTE_ID       
                    WHERE C.CATENTRY_ID = D.CATENTRY_ID                     
                    AND C.BUYABLE = 1 
                    AND C.MARKFORDELETE = 0 
                    AND D.PUBLISHED = 1 
                    AND R.CATENTRY_ID_PARENT = C.CATENTRY_ID 
                    --AND NOT (INTEGERVALUE1 = '0' AND STRINGVALUE2='true')
                    AND C.CATENTRY_ID = AVL.CATENTRY_ID 
                    AND C.CATENTTYPE_ID = 'ProductBean' 
                    AND R.CATENTRY_ID_PARENT IN ( 
                    SELECT DISTINCT CC.CATENTRY_ID 
                    FROM CATENTRY CC, CATGPENREL RR, CATGROUP GG, CATGRPDESC DD 
                    WHERE RR.CATALOG_ID =  10901
                    AND CC.CATENTRY_ID = RR.CATENTRY_ID 
                    AND GG.CATGROUP_ID = RR.CATGROUP_ID 
                    AND GG.CATGROUP_ID = DD.CATGROUP_ID 
                    AND DD.NAME NOT LIKE 'PULLED%'  
                    ) ORDER BY R.CATENTRY_ID_PARENT FOR READ ONLY WITH UR
```

However in the second case when, the assignment of `CAT1ID` is not working. It is throwing a error as below

`Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=CAT1ID, DRIVER=4.1.85`

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-206_sqlstate_42703.html

Comment: yeah i already got the link but i want an idea on how to assign the value for the CAT1id parameter

Answer (score 0):

In your second CASE there is the most inner query

```
select attribute_id from attribute M4 where M4.name in ('clubExclusive') and M4.catentry_id=CAT1ID
```

and in this query sql is trying to find a `CAT1D` in `atrribute` table. Actually you have CAT1D field only in outter most query.

You may use `CURSOR` and take `CAT1D` value into a variable then use in your main query.